# Why SpEL support doesn't work in Spring Data JPA @Query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

I'm trying to avoid redundancy with passing second argument to method with list size. Instead, I use EL, but I have an error:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set:
>   [**$synthetic$__1] [SELECT distinct b FROM Book b join b.bookHashtags
>   as ht where ht.hashtagName in :tags group by b.uniqueIdentifier having
>   count(ht.uniqueIdentifier) = :**$synthetic$__1]

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Book> {
    @Query("SELECT distinct b FROM Book b join b.bookHashtags as ht where ht.hashtagName in :tags " +
        "group by b.uniqueIdentifier having count(ht.uniqueIdentifier) = :#{#tags.size()}")
    List<Book> findAllBooksContainedTags(@Param("tags") Set<String> tags);

}
```

I use spring-data-jpa 1.11.0.RELEASE. I know that this feature was developed in 1.4 release. Why it doesn't work in my case...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is simple: arbitrary expressions are not implemented/supported.

Please check carefully on Spring Data JPA documentaiton regarding [Using SpEL expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions)

> As of Spring Data JPA release 1.4 we support the usage of **restricted SpEL template expressions** in manually defined queries via @Query

And the table of supported expressions contains only

> **Variable**: entityName
>
> **Usage**: select x from #{#entityName} x
>
> **Description**: Inserts the entityName of the domain type associated with the given Repository. The entityName is resolved as follows: If the domain type has set the name property on the @Entity annotation then it will be used. Otherwise the simple class-name of the domain type will be used.