# Use application properties in native spring @Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-el

I have a repository with a method that executes a native query to get data from the database:

```
public interface ObjRepository extends CrudRepository<Obj, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT obj.*\n" +
            "FROM obj\n" +
            "WHERE obj.value < #{${property.name}} and obj.value2 < :arg", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Obj> getObjs(@Param("arg") int arg);
```

I'm trying to use a property as a constant in the query. The property is defined in the `application.properties` file as `property.name=300`. When I try to run the query, I get an exception:

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "{"`

If I replace `#{${property.name}}` with the actual number in the string, the query works fine. Is my SpEL syntax wrong? How can I use a property defined in application.properties in a query string?

Comment: Try `'${property.name}'` or `#{'${property.name}'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46837353/11733759):

arbitrary expressions are **not implemented/supported**.

Please check on Spring Data JPA documentaiton regarding [Using SpEL expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions)

> As of Spring Data JPA release 1.4 we support the usage of **restricted SpEL template expressions** in manually defined queries via @Query
>
> Spring Data JPA supports a variable called `entityName`.

#### Other Soultion

[There was a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53171308/11733759). And you can try something from [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53171535/11733759).

Change your `ObjRepository`

```java
public interface ObjRepository extends CrudRepository<Obj, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT obj.*\n" +
                "FROM obj\n" +
                "WHERE obj.value < :value and obj.value2 < :arg", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Obj> getObjs(@Param("arg") int arg, @Param("value") int value);
```

And then you can use it like this

```java
@Service
public class SomeService {

    @Value("${property.name}")
    private int value;

    @Autowired
    private ObjRepository objRepository ;

    public List<Obj> getObjs(int arg) {
        return objRepository.getObjs(arg, value);
    }
}
```